# Flutter Widgets Visibility on Tap

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, touch, visibility

I have custom paint as parent in all widget. The user can add as many widget like (text,textformfield,image,button,icon) as he want. The color of parent widget is set to transparent as default and when the user tap once the color is set as white for only that widget. Here, when user tap any widget all the widgets parent color turns to white but I want to set the color white of only that widget which is tapped at a time.

My code:

```
  var isSingleTapped=false;
     Stack(
     children: <Widget>[
      Container(
      width: 200,
      height:200
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isSingleTapped = true;
          });},
        child: WidgetHandle(
               handleColor:
              isSingleTapped ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
          child: TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: getAddress(),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ))),
  Container(
      width: 200,
      height:200
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isSingleTapped = true;
          });},
        child: WidgetHandle(
               handleColor:
              isSingleTapped ? Colors.white : 
                Colors.transparent,
          child: Icon(
              icon:Icons.face,
              color:white,
              size:32
            ),
          ))),
         ..OtherWidget..
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use different variables for different widgets to handle their colour or if you have more number of widgets you can use array to store the states.
**For Less Multiple Widgets**

```
var isSingleTapped1=false,isSingleTapped2=false;
                 Stack(
                 children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height:200
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isSingleTapped1 = true;
                      });},
                    child: WidgetHandle(
                           handleColor:
                          isSingleTapped1 ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
                      child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: getAddress(),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ))),
                      Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height:200
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isSingleTapped2 = true;
                      });},
                    child: WidgetHandle(
                           handleColor:
                          isSingleTapped2 ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
                      child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: getAddress(),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ))),
                      Container(..same code...),
                      Container(..same code...),
```

**For more number of Multiple widgets**

```
int numberOfContainers=10; 
List<bool> isSingleTapped=[];
for(i=0;i<numberOfContainers;i++)
    isSingleTapped[i]=false;
```

First we will make a array of bools with the number of widgets we want then run `List.generate` to generate same kind of widgets with our logic

```
             Stack(
                 children: List.generate(numberOfContainers,(position){
                     return Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height:200
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isSingleTapped[position] = true;
                      });},
                    child: WidgetHandle(
                           handleColor:
                          isSingleTapped[position] ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
                      child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: getAddress(),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ))),
                 })
```

**Update**
If you want to take complete custom widgets you have to take a `List<Widget>` and add your widgets to that `List`.Then you can call `List.generate()` and pass the particular position of the array to the child of the `WidgetHandle`

```
List<Widget> list=[];
Stack(
                     children: List.generate(numberOfContainers,(position){
                         return Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height:200
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isSingleTapped[position] = true;
                          });},
                        child: WidgetHandle(
                               handleColor:
                              isSingleTapped[position] ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
                          child: list[position]
                          ))),
                     })
```

Comment: Widget can be as many as user want because user can add more widget and also can delete if he want

Comment: The 2nd example is for that you can use n number of widgets in that

Comment: In this case which data type is i?  for(i=0;i<numberOfContainers;i++)=>
               isSingleTapped[i]=false;  ..If integer it cannot be assigned with bool

Comment: `i` is integer isSIngleTapped is a array of bool, `isSIngleTapped[i]` means i no element of the array i.e. a bool..Test the code it's running.

Comment: I'll revert back after sometime.. Please wait

Comment: i've given the perfect answer ..You have to take an array of bools which represent values for each container and create them dynamically..i've taken 10 for example you can make that dynamic

Comment: List.generate create same type of widget isn't it?But in my condition there are different types of widgets

Comment: fully custom ..some are textfield,images,icons,text etc

Comment: It is giving error saying: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class DataModel {
  bool isTapped = false;
  Widget widget;

  DataModel(this.widget,this.isTapped);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _randomWidgets = [
    Text('Some Text Widget'),
    FlutterLogo(size: 50,),
    Icon(Icons.check_circle,),
    FlatButton(child: Text('Some Button Button Widget'),onPressed: (){},),
  ];

  // just to pick random element in array
  final _random = new Random();

  List<DataModel> _widgetList = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,index){
        Widget widget = _widgetList[index].widget;
        Color color = _widgetList[index].isTapped ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent;
        return widgetHandle(handleColor: color, child: widget,index: index);
      },itemCount: _widgetList.length,),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addWidget,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  //adds random widget to the list, this it where the user can add widgets 
  _addWidget(){
    _widgetList.add(DataModel(_randomWidgets[_random.nextInt(_randomWidgets.length)], false));
    setState(() {
    });
  }

  Widget widgetHandle({@required Color handleColor, @required Widget child, @required int index})
  {
    return GestureDetector(
    onLongPress: (){
      //this where the user can remove widgets from the list
      _widgetList.removeAt(index);
      setState(() {
      });
    },
    onTap: (){
      setState(() {
        if(_widgetList[index].isTapped)
        _widgetList[index].isTapped = false;
        else
          _widgetList[index].isTapped = true;
      });
    }, child: Container(child: child,color: handleColor,width: 200,height: 200,));
  }

}
```

Comment: there are multiple widgets but not exact to say the numbers of widgets

Comment: Okay, then why don't you put all of them in a ListView or Column and hide or show that instead?

Comment: Also could you make your code more readable? It's very difficult to read.

Comment: Okay, I now understand your question. Using stack would place the widgets on top of each other making it difficult to see the changes consider using a ListView and also you need to create a data model to store the states of the widgets

Comment: it was great but I was using stack because at first some widget are already placed there and there is option of buttons for adding different widgets like adding textfield,images,icons.When I click the textfield button new textfield will be added,when i click icons button new icon will be added like that way....

Comment: so you can put all of those widgets in a horizontal list  and put them at the bottom so when they click on any of them it appears in the list

Comment: I can't use list as they all are draggable widget and can be placed anywhere user wants..